# Javascript classic script vs module scope

Tags: javascript, javascript-scope

I have some strange behavior in my javascript front end code so I am asking a going back to basics question. First I will setup some examples.

script1.js

```
var script1Var = "script variable";
function script1Test(){
  console.log("hello from script1 test");
}
```

script2.js

```
function script2Test(){
  console.log("hello from script2 test");
}
```

module1.js

```
export default function module1Test(){
  console.log("hello from module1 test");
}
```

module2.js

```
export default function module2Test(){
  console.log("hello from module2 test");
}
```

test_page1.html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
 </head>
</html>
```

test_page2.html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="module" src="module1.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="module2.js"></script>
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
 </head>
</html>
```

Here are my questions:

1. During runtime because of how `test_page1.html` is laid out I presume that `script2.js` can call functions in `script1.js` without the need of any imports, but can  `script1.js` call functions in `script2.js`? Basically does order matter? I am quite positive that it does.
2. In `test_page2.html` are functions from `module1.js` and `module2.js` visible to `script1.js` and `script2.js`? If not, how can they be made visible to them?
3. In `test_page2.html` are functions from `module1.js` visible to `module2.js` without the use of imports?

Basically my questions boil down to, how can a classic script (does not have exports in it) be used in modules? And how can modules be used in classic scripts. Converting the classic script into a module is not an option here since there is a lot of code that depends on using it as a classic script. And the same for modules, they can not be converted to classic scripts since there is other code using them as modules.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

> 1. [...] but can script1.js call functions in script2.js? Basically does order matter? I am quite positive that it does.

It depends. `script1.js` cannot call functions from `script2.js` while its being evaluated. I.e. something like

```
// script1.js
script2Test();
```

wouldn't work.

But it can call those functions as long as it is *after* `script2.js` loaded. For example in response to an event:

```
// script1.js
document.body.onclick = function() {
  script2Test();
}
```

> 2. In test_page2.html are functions from module1.js and module2.js visible to script1.js and script2.js?

No. Each module creates a separate scope. Exports can only be accessed by importing them.

> If not, how can they be made visible to them?

The modules would have to explicitly create global variables, e.g. by assigning a property to `window`:

```
window.module1Test = module1Test;
```

But also here, such a function would only be callable after the module loaded/was evaluated.

The better solution (at least I believe this works in "normal" scripts) would be to import the module dynamically, via the `import` function:

```
import('./module1Test.js').then(exports => console.log(exports));
```

> 3. In test_page2.html are functions from module1.js visible to module2.js without the use of imports?

No. As I said, every module creates its own scope.